# c++ gpa calculator not accepting grade input

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int course, numberOfClasses; //declare variables
    double gradePointTotal = 0, gradePointAve; //initialize to 0
    string grade;

    cout << "GPA Calculator \n";
    cout << "\n Enter the number of classes ";
    cin >> numberOfClasses; // enter number of classes

    for (course = 1; course <= numberOfClasses; course++ ) // define loop
    {
        cout << "\n Enter a letter grade for class number " << course << ": ";
        cin >> grade; //Enter grade
        if ( grade == "A" || grade == "a") //accepts upper and lower case
            gradePointTotal = gradePointTotal + 4;
        else if ( grade == "B" || grade == "b")
            gradePointTotal = gradePointTotal + 3;
        else if ( grade == "C" || grade == "c")
            gradePointTotal = gradePointTotal + 2;
        else if ( grade == "D" || grade == "d")
            gradePointTotal = gradePointTotal + 1;
        else if ( grade == "F" || grade == "f")
            gradePointTotal = gradePointTotal + 0;

        gradePointAve = gradePointTotal / numberOfClasses; // calculate the GPA
        cout << "\n Your GPA is: " << gradePointAve << endl; // display GPA

    }
}
```

I'm a newb to C++. I am not exactly sure why...but my output is not correct. This program calculates gpa. I am able to enter the number of classes I am using, however-I can not enter the letter grades. I was getting an error with my line: 
cin >> grade; 
but I was able to fix the error message by adding #include . However, it is not doing what is expected....
Why can I not enter my letter grades when the console screen pops up?

Comment: Why are you declaring `int course, numberOfClasses;` where they have no right to be declared? Just do `for(int course = 1; ...` ; `int gradePointAve = ...`.

Comment: Please answer these questions by editing your question: What do you expect the code to do? Why? What happens instead?

Comment: #include what? "stdafx.h" ?

Comment: If you use either `toupper()` or `tolower()`, you would only need to make one comparison per letter grade.

Comment: If you use `char` type instead of string, you could use a `switch` statement instead of the `if-else` ladder.

Comment: Obligatory:  Debugger.  Use a debugger before posting to StackOverflow.  A debugger allows you to execute each statement separately while *watching* the values of variables.

Comment: Averages are the *sum* divided by the *quantity*.  In your loop, you need to calculate the *sum*.  After your loop, you can calculate the average because you know the total (sum) and the quantity (`numberOfClasses`).  Search the internet for "how to calculate average".

Answer (score 1):

```
gradePointAve = gradePointTotal / numberOfClasses; // wrong
```

is wrong, since you would imply that gradePointTotal contains all grades. but since you are looping, that's not the case.
You need to set `course`, not `numberOfClasses` as the quotient:

```
gradePointAve = gradePointTotal / course; // correct
```

at least that gives you the correct result.

And remove `#include "stdafx.h"`, you don't need that. It's not really nice to have standard libraries in your project folder. And again, you don't need it for the code.

Comment: 1 for getting rid of `stdafx.h`.  Also, please add discussion about integer truncation.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  I assumed all newbies use integers for the sum and quantity.